# Best way to convert JSON data and implement values in checkbox,text,drop down or radio input type?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to find the most efficient and generic solution for my single page app. There is 5 different tabs. Each tab is loading data in JSON object. Once user clicks on the tab JSON data is populated in the object with unique key. If user clicks on the Edit button I'm looping through JSON data and populating form fields. Here is my problem I have checkbox, radio, text and drop down menu fields on my form. Each data type requires different data type. My data in JSON object is not converted for checkbox or radio type input fields. I'm wondering what is the best way to approach this problem?

Here is example of my JSON data:

```
var jsonData = {
   "frmTab1":{"st_fname":"mike","st_lname":"cook","st_iseligible":"yes"},
   "frmTab2":{"sa_condition":"yes","sa_evaluation":"no"},
   "frmTab3":{"se_respons":"yes","se_option":"3"},
   ... and so on
}
```

Here is my JQuery function that populates the form:

```
$('input[name="hmButton"]').on('click', function formSubmit(){
    var btnVal = $(this).val();

    if(btnVal == 'Edit'){
        var jsonKey = $(this).attr('data-json'); //In data json is from id value

        if($.isEmptyObject(jsonData[jsonKey])){
            console.log('no data');
        }else{
            $.each(jsonData[jsonKey], function(index, element) {
                //Here I need to check the input type and set checked if type is checkbox, or value if it's radio type, and same thing for drop down.
                $('#frm' + index).val(element); 
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I was wondering if this could be done with another JSON object that will have key for each field with input type that is not equal text. If anyone can help please let me know. I'm trying to make this dynamic. This might be use in some other situation in my app. Thank you.

Comment: you could always make the properties into objects that store the input type, `"frmTab1":{"st_fname": {"value": "mike", "input": "text"}, ... }"`

Comment: @PatrickBarr I can pull the input type while looping through JSON data. Something like: $('#frm' + index).attr('type').

Answer (score 1):

This...

```
var jsonData = {
    'frmTab1': {
        'st_fname': 'mike',
        'st_lname': 'cook',
        'st_iseligible': 'yes'
    },
    'frmTab2': {
        'sa_condition': 'yes',
        'sa_evaluation': 'no'
    },
    'frmTab3': {
        'se_respons': 'yes',
        'se_option': '3'
    }
}
```

... is a JavaScript `Object`.  JSON is a text-based data-interchange format, and although it's written in **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation (hence JSON) try to avoid confusing JavaScript `Object`s with JSON data.  Now that's out of the way...  :)

Although JSON keys have to be defined between quotes ("...") as long as the keys in a JavaScript Object obey the usual syntax requirements the quotes for keys can be dispensed with...

```
var jsonData = {
    frmTab1: {
        st_fname: 'mike',
        st_lname: 'cook',
        st_iseligible: 'yes'
    },
    frmTab2: {
        sa_condition: 'yes',
        sa_evaluation: 'no'
    },
    frmTab3: {
        se_respons: 'yes',
        se_option: '3'
    }
};
```

Your suggestion of referencing another Object which acts as an intermediary between the function which populates your page and the information in the `jsonData` variable is workable - perhaps something like this...

```
var dataMap = {
    waypoint_1: jsonData.frmTab1,
    waypoint_2: jsonData.frmTab2,
    waypoint_3: jsonData.frmTab3
    /* ... etc ... */
};
```

What I have called 'waypoint_n' here would reflect the properties/strings you're expecting to retrieve from your page element attributes - so that Something like...

```
var dKey = /* attribute value or property (String) */
var data = dataMap[ dKey ];
```

...would then place the required information from the `jsonData` Object in the `data` variable.

However, as you already have this information in an Object (`jsonData`) why not simply amend its keys to reflect the attribute values you're expecting?

You may find these links useful:

- Eloquent JavaScript: [The Secret Life of Objects](http://eloquentjavascript.net/06_object.html)
- Eloquent JavaScript: [Data Structures: Objects and Arrays](http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html)
- MDN: [Working with JSON data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON)